# Выбор активных полей в html форме

Tags: html, css, html-form

Есть такая вот форма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Каким образом можно реализовать активацию полей этой формы с помощью списка множественного выбора? Допустим, конкретного пользователя я хочу оповещать только о приближении срока оплаты и проведении технических работ. В списке я выбираю эти строки и хочу, чтобы активными стали только поля, которые я выбрал в списке. 
Возможно существует более красивый способ реализации, может и не через [select](/questions/tagged/select), а например, [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox)'ы или [radio](/questions/tagged/radio). Помогите пожалуйста советом.

И каким образом можно занести в поле таблицы сразу несколько пунктов списка? Например, я выбираю Срок оплаты и Технические работы, а в базу заносится только один выбранный пункт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Определение "активных" какое? Видимые? Незаблокированные?

Comment: Без разницы. Главное, чтобы человек, который будет этим пользоваться, не смог вводить данные в поля, которые он не выбрал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привязал к каждой [textarea](/questions/tagged/textarea) [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="agree_pay" style='height: 18px; width: 18px;' onclick="agreeForm(this.form)">

<script>
    function agreeForm(f) {

        if (f.agree_pay.checked) f.pay.disabled = 0 
        else f.pay.disabled = 1
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`focus()`? Или вы хотите заблокировать сами textarea, тогда это делается через атрибут `readonly`.

Comment: А как связать мой выбор в списке с блокированием textarea?